# Is a function surjective in a neighbourhood of point with nonzero derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ be  continuous function such that   $f'(x_0)\neq 0$  for some $x_0\in [a,b]$.

Does there exist $\delta_1, \delta_2>0$ such that any $y\in (f(x_0)-\delta_2, f(x_0)+\delta_2)$, $y\in [c,d]$, can be expressed in the form
$$
y=f(x) 
$$
for  $x\in (x_0-\delta_1, x_0+\delta_1)$, $x\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without lost of generality you can assume that $x_0 = 0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.
Then from $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$$ you get that $f(x)$ takes both negative and positive values near $0$. Namely, there is $x_1 < 0$ such that $f(x_1) < 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ such that $f(x_2) >0$. Then by the continuity of $f$ any $y \in [f(x_1),f(x_2)]$ can be expressed as $y = f(x)$ for $x \in [x_1,x_2]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the closed intervals with open ones (the conditions don't really make sense with open ones), then the answer is yes, by the constant rank theorem. More directly, local surjectivity can fail only if the image of $f$ near $y_0 = f(x_0)$ looks like a half-interval $(a, y_0]$ or $[y_0, a)$, or else a single point $y_0$. Show that both cases are eliminated by the condition that $f'(x_0) \not= 0$.